# Display Current time into database using onclick()

Tags: asp.net, database

I have a doubt in Asp.Net that is Whenever click the button i want to store the current time into database using Onclick, can anybody suggest me please.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server you can store the current time by using GETDATE() function in SQL.

Such as :

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Id,ClickTime) VALUES (5, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.Now` in asp.net .....

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table_name (username, logindate) VALUES (@USERNAME, @DATE)", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", tbUserName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", DateTime.Now);
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you Harshit Tailor, first of all i want to insert current time into database when click the button how?